# Remove line breaks from lines that don't start with

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove all new line break Except after lines that start with a ">" character. I have tried `^(?!>)(?<=.*)\n` but it returns 0 results. I'm using this in NotePad++.  I have 10s of thousands of line breaks in some large protein sequence files and I want the Protein sequences to be on a single line after its >Information_line.

Input:

```
>ref|XP_008| angi [enzyme1]  
MSGSSWLILSLVV  
VTAAQSTPEEQVKTFLDKFNQE  
AEDLYHQSSLAAWNYNTNI  
TEENSQQMNDAGEIWS  
AFYNEQSKIA
```

Expected result:

```
>ref|XP_008| angi [enzyme1] MSGSSWLILSLVVVTAAQSTPEEQVKTFLDKFNQEAEDLYHQSSLAAWNYNTNITEENSQQMNDAGEIWSAFYNEQSKIA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!>)       # negative lookahead, make we haven't ">" after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Works beautifully! THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: `^(?!>)(?<=.*)\n`.
The regexp says that there should be no '>' character right after a line beginning, then there can be any characters that are not captured and then we capture a newline character.

Comment: I tried this regexp in Notepad++ but unfortunately, it returns 0 hits.